# whenever I press number key it act as as a function key corsair keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need some help. I have a corsair k70 rgb mk.2 and whenever I press number key it act as as a function key. How do I disable it?
[image]

[image]
It's pressing 2 keys together, there isn't any assigned key in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If by some chance you haven't solved this, try following the reset guidelines (`hold esc key while plugging the usb in`) to reset any onboard hardware profiles.  You can also do that inside icue 3/4/5 but I would recommend the manual method to rule it all out.

You should double check you don't have a remap or macro action set inside icue, and finally make sure there isn't something like autohotkey running that may mimic the appearance of a dual kb_event.  Also try an alternate keyboard to confirm functionality differs.